# System.IndexOutOfRangeException on SalesForce OutBound Message Listener

Tags: c#, web-services, http, salesforce, outbound

I have a webservice in ASMX and I am trying to create a Listener and here is what I have in the webservice.cs file

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for WebService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
class MyNotificationListener : NotificationBinding
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]

    public notificationsResponse Notifications(notifications n)
    {
        Method.SendMail("info@domain.com", "test@domain.com", "Here I am ", "I am loaded ", "", "");// This is to see if it loaded
        notificationsResponse r = new notificationsResponse();
        r.Ack = true;
        return r;
    }

}
```

in my outboun message configuration I am calling this webservice like so `www.domain/webservice.asmx/Notification` but when I load this service I See the following:

```
`System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerType..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)`
```

In my config file I have the following

```
`<webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
        <add name="HttpSoap" />
      </protocols>
    </webServices>`
```

Here is what I have in the Notification Object this was generated from WSDL file to a class using wsdl.exe as directed in [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_listener.htm) example.

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "4.7.3081.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound")]
public partial class notifications
{

    private string organizationIdField;

    private string actionIdField;

    private string sessionIdField;

    private string enterpriseUrlField;

    private string partnerUrlField;

    private LeadNotification[] notificationField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string OrganizationId {
        get {
            return this.organizationIdField;
        }
        set {
            this.organizationIdField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string ActionId {
        get {
            return this.actionIdField;
        }
        set {
            this.actionIdField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string SessionId {
        get {
            return this.sessionIdField;
        }
        set {
            this.sessionIdField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string EnterpriseUrl {
        get {
            return this.enterpriseUrlField;
        }
        set {
            this.enterpriseUrlField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string PartnerUrl {
        get {
            return this.partnerUrlField;
        }
        set {
            this.partnerUrlField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Notification")]
    public LeadNotification[] Notification {
        get {
            return this.notificationField;
        }
        set {
            this.notificationField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you reach the method "notificationsResponse" ?
try to put  a breakpoint to see if it hit.
also try to invoke the asmx file bia the browser interface.

Comment: No, it does not reach that I don't know why I put in another simple method and I was able to invoke it via url but this one notification never gets hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, After looking at your code I see that in your webservice the implementation of the public interface is named wrong, when I generated the Class with a WSDL from salesforce it creates the interface and its named `INotificationBinding` not `NotificationBinding` which makes me think that you didn't create the class properly from the wsdl, in the example you shown above that you are following says to use `wsdl.exe /serverInterface leads.wsdl`.

Did you create the above class notification using the wsdl.exe ? if so did you make sure it was using the option of `/serverInterface` this is important(See image below),[image] on salesforce it clearly mentions that you need to implement a class that calls the notification interface if this is not properly handled it will give the error of `System.IndexOutOfRangeException`

Please try again using the serverinterface option. That should fix the issue.

Comment: Yes! that was int! I regenerated it with that option and it worked!

Answer (score -1):

I think you can't reach this method because you try to pass an object : "notifications n" 
and using a GET request. 
you can't do GET to this method. 
anyway the Exception you describe does not seem to be related. it's in your code . 
try to share the Code you use to consume this service